# Function Pointer with void* return and void* parameters

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I wrote a function pointer that has all void* so that it can be used for any numeric value

1. int
2. float
3. double.

But it is working only for the `int` addition function

For `float` and `double` addition functions, it throws compile time error.
Why is that so ?

If you uncomment the last two `printf` lines, you would receive error

```
#include<stdio.h>

int int_add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

float float_add(float x, float y) {
    return x + y;
}

double double_add(double x, double y) {
    return x + y;
}
void* do_operation(void* (*op)(void*, void*), void* x, void* y) {
    return op(x, y);
}

void main(void) {

    printf("Sum= %d\n",(int*) do_operation(int_add, 1, 2));
    /*printf("Sum= %f\n",(float*) do_operation(float_add, 1.20, 2.50));*/
    /*printf("Sum= %lf\n",(double*) do_operation(double_add, 1.20, 2.50));*/
    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void *` is a pointer type. You're not passing pointers, you're passing values, so that's not going to compile. It accidentally "works" for `int` because pointers themselves are represented as integers by most C compilers.

If you pass pointers to `int`, `float`, and `double` instead of the `int`, `float`, and `double` themselves, you will avoid that compiler error. You'd also need to change `int_add` and friends to take pointers, and you'd have to make sure you dereferenced the pointers before using them. You'll also have to return pointers, which means you'll have to `malloc` some memory on the heap, because the stack memory assigned to your local variables will be invalid once your function exits. You'll then have to `free` it all later... in the end, this is going to result in something considerably more complicated than the problem it appears you are trying to solve.

I have to ask why you are trying to do this? C is really not the best language for this type of pattern. I'd suggest just calling the `int_add`, `float_add`, etc. functions directly instead of trying to abstract them in this way.

Comment: thank you. Rewrote the code as per your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0):

So as per @charles-srstka suggestion I rewrote the code and then it worked as I wanted

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int* int_add(int *x, int *y) {
    int *c = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *c = *(int*)x + *(int*)y;
    return c;
}

float* float_add(float *x, float *y) {
    float *c = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    *c = *(float*)x + *(float*)y;
    return c;
}

void* do_operation(void* (*op)(void*, void*), void* x, void* y) {
    return op(x, y);
}

void main(void) {

    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;                                               
    int *c;
    c = do_operation(int_add, &a, &b);
    printf("%d\n",*c);
    free(c);

    float x = 1.1;                                               
    float y = 2.2;                                               
    float *z;
    z = do_operation(float_add, &x, &y);
    printf("%f\n",*z);
    free(z);
}
```